# Copying InputStreamReader

Tags: java

Can somebody provide a source of

```
public class CopyingInputStreamReader extends InputStreamReader {
   public  CopyingInputStreamReader(InputStream is, OutputStream copyStream) {
  .....
```

The implementation should copy whatever got read to output stream. I have my implementation, but my HD crashed, so I need to recover it. Please respond in next 5 minutes, otherwise I will figure ot myself.

Comment: 5 minutes over. Now its your turn to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't do this at the reader level. I would write an `InputStream` which overrides all the methods methods *from* `InputStream`, delegating to the input stream that's been passed to the constructor and writes to the output stream after each read, before returning the data to the caller. For example:

```
@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int start, int length) throws IOException
{
    int ret = input.read(buffer, start, length);
    output.write(buffer, start, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

The reason I wouldn't make at extend `InputStreamReader` is that the results of all the `read` operations would be *text* data - which you'd then need to write to your `OutputStream` somehow...

Of course, if you really want to convert from one encoding to another, it would be worth extending `Reader` instead of `InputStream`, take another `Reader` to delegate to and a `Writer` to write to. Again, then you stay within one realm (text) instead of being part of the conversion yourself.

EDIT: It strikes me that I forgot to mention you also need to override the non-read methods to either just delegate directly to the input stream, or throw an exception. (For example, you *probably* don't want to support mark/reset.)

Comment: It makes sense, and actually I have such implementation, however I need a quick solution for debug purpose only, so I do not care about losing encoding.

Comment: @Dmitriy: Why do you think it would be faster to write the wrong code than the right code? Either of these solutions will be just as easy to plug into your other code, and will be cleaner as well.

Comment: @Jon: Just for the record, your suggested solution (which is spot on) is an example of the decorator pattern: http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/decorator-pattern/

Comment: @Jon: It is major difference between people creating software and people who create theories about it. No one software project of reasonable complexity would never end if people follow your suggestion. Another topic is defining wrong code. You may guess that besides of very obvious cases definition of wrong and right code is foggy until you do not know purpose.

Comment: @Dmitriy: What I proposed is cleaner (by your own admission, assuming I understood your comment correctly) *and would take no more effort*. It seems you think I don't actually create any software... I'm a professional software engineer, not just a writer... But in general, yes, I *do* like to actually take a bit of time to do something properly - because shortcuts usually end up *costing* time in the long run, given how long software tends to be maintained for. (Continued.)

Comment: For example, I would typically set up source control on a backed up server for any software I actually care about. Yes, that takes a bit longer to start with... but then if your hard disk crashes, you don't lose your work...

Comment: @Jon: So provide complete source of your solution, because currently I rated your answer as correct, however my issue is still not resolved.

Comment: @Dmitriy: I'm busy helping other people right now - I've given *one* sample method, it's just a matter of overriding the others in the same way. If you're having problems implementing my solution, explain those problems rather than either just demanding code or denigrating the idea of doing the right thing.

Comment: @Jon: Sorry if my question was misleading it wasn't about how to do that, I did it hundreds times for different purpose, I just asked if somebody has source handy so I can avoid writing another implementation or search in my backup archives. And I really appreciate your efforts to help me and other people as well, keep good job and take care. I also liked you tried to offend me, you seem ambitious person and never admitting that you were wrong

Comment: @Dmitriy: I still don't think I *was* wrong in this case. (If you look elsewhere you'll find plenty of places where I've been wrong and admitted so.) I still believe my solution is more elegant than extending `InputStreamReader` and won't take any longer to implement. I also think if you'd taken as much time to just sit down and implement my suggestion as you have arguing about it, you'd be done by now.

Answer (score 2):

Use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) with

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

Comment: Agree with Peter... I'm just want to comment with commons IO IOUtils copy, or spring util FileCopyUtils copy.  I add thumb too with Harry Joy, that he needs to figure it out after 5 mins :p

Comment: I wanted to give him answer which is fine, unless its `homework`.

Comment: So lets say I wanted to use this for unit testing.  In my real environment those streams are provided to me either from a bluetooth socket (android) or a ServerSocket/Socket.  Which implementation would be most appropriate for unit testing?

Comment: @Ivan Either. I would do what you think is simplest.